# XMLParseException expected ' or "

Tags: php, oracle

I POST an xml string to a oracle system:

```
$xmlData='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML
  SYSTEM \'http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.008/cXML.dtd\'>
<cXML payloadID="2016-02-19T09:08:47-06:00.Wasd++l5OasdIYgTs= .357asd659@423asd3892" timestamp="2016-02-19T09:08:47-06:00" version="1.2.008" xml:lang="en-US">
    <Header>
        <From>
```

Etcetera

but the oracle system sees this:

```
Shopping Cart XML: <?xml version=
XMLParserException
XMLParserException
oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException: Expected ' or ".
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors1(XMLError.java:320)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.scanQuotedString(XMLReader.java:1800)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.scanQuotedString(XMLReader.java:1890)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.scanXMLDecl(XMLReader.java:3107)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.pushXMLReader(XMLReader.java:275)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:333)
        at oracle.apps.icx.punchout.parsers.XMLParser.parseByDOM(XMLParser.java:158)
```

do I need to use htmlspecialchars on the xml string?

Comment: Where is your sql statement??

Comment: SQL? why I need sql??

Comment: So what "oracle" product are you referring to?

Comment: oracle i procurement